# Why are predict.lm and matrix multiplication giving different predictions?

Tags: r, lm, predict, model.matrix

I've been fitting a model in R with lm() and making predictions 'manually' using matrix multiplication.

When checking results against predictions made using predict.lm() I've noticed that the results differ, but only when I'm making predictions on a new dataset (i.e., one on which the model wasn't trained) *and* where I apply polynomials (or splines) to the predictors.

Can anyone explain why this is the case? I thought the two approaches would give the same answer irrespective of whether I'm using a new dataset or polynomials.

Reproducible example below.

```
# Make data, fit model
set.seed(1); df_train = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(3000), ncol = 3))
set.seed(2); df_test = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(300), ncol = 3))
fit = lm(X1 ~ poly(X2, 2) + poly(X3, 2), data = df_train)
# fit = lm(X1 ~ X2 + X3, data = df_train) #no issues using linear terms
mm_train = model.matrix(formula(fit), df_train)
mm_test = model.matrix(formula(fit), df_test)

# Using predict and matrix multiplication give same results on train data
preds_1 = round(predict(fit, df_train), 5)
preds_2 = round(mm_train %*% fit$coefficients, 5)
all(preds_1 == preds_2) #TRUE

# Using predict and matrix multiplication give different results on test data
preds_1 = round(predict(fit, df_test), 5) 
preds_2 = round(mm_test %*% fit$coefficients, 5)
all(preds_1 == preds_2)  #FALSE
```

Comment: see `?makepredictcall`; `poly()` constructs orthogonal polynomials on the basis of the current data set, extra care is needed to predict ...

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker, that's very helpful

Comment: I think the behavior can be explained by the fact that your data set are random numbers. I assume that the training data are predicted correctly because your models are overfit, analogous to having a single line going through 2 given points. On the test data the predictions fail, because there is no pattern in the data. If you look at summary(fit), you will notice that the p values are terrible. What you could try instead is to construct X1 as a function of X2 and X3 with some added noise, for example X1 = X2 + X3 + 0.01*rnorm().

Comment: Thanks, but the random numbers are there just to create a reproducible example. The issue I describe (predictions differing depending on whether I use predict.lm or matrix algebra) isn't dependent on having a relationship between the predictors and response.